# Installation of Oracle 11gR2 in Oracle Linux 7

Tags: oracle, linux, installation

Installation of Oracle 11gR2 is failed with below error, on Oracle Linux 7 OS.

```
> INFO: Building Client Shared Libraries INFO: Building Client Shared
> Libraries INFO: The output of this make operation is also available
> at: '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/install/make.log' INFO: 
> 
> INFO: Start output from spawned process: INFO:
> ---------------------------------- INFO: 
> 
> INFO: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/bin/genclntsh
> 
> INFO: /bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++_nonshared
> 
> INFO: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> 
> INFO: genclntsh: Failed to link libclntsh.so.11.1
> 
> INFO: make: *** [client_sharedlib] Error 1
> 
> INFO: End output from spawned process. INFO:
> ---------------------------------- INFO: Exception thrown from action: make Exception Name: MakefileException Exception String: Error in
> invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile
> '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See
> '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2017-11-09_12-52-50AM.log'
> for details. Exception Severity: 1
```

Let me know that i need to try reinstall it or any work around can be done.

Comment: Does the `/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2017-11-09_12-52-50AM.log` show any hints? Most likely you are missing some dependencies. Did you install the `oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall` package? This package is available for 12cR2 and 11gR2, too

Comment: Have you carefully read and implemented the prerequisites? It seems the key line is "`cannot find -lstdc++_nonshared`" - have you investigated this?

Comment: @Vérace Actually, Prerequisite check is failed, please go through this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189465/oracle-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-7-prerequisite-condition-failed-for/189479?noredirect=1#comment370281_189479

Comment: @azardin I don't think, that Vérace meant the prerequisite check but the installation prerequisites as per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/pre_install.htm#LADBI7534)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the missing `libstdc++` package.

[Linking using g++ fails searching for -lstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086072/linking-using-g-fails-searching-for-lstdc)

In your previous question, on your screenshot, you have multiple missing packages, including `libstdc++`.

Comment: Note that you need both, 32 and 64 bit packages

Comment: @jmk No, you do not. `Starting with Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.2), all the 32-bit packages, except for gcc-32bit-4.3, listed in the following table are no longer required for installing a database on Linux x86-64. Only the 64-bit packages are required. However, for any Oracle Database 11g release before 11.2.0.2, both the 32-bit and 64-bit packages listed in the following table are required.`. The question is about 11.2.0.4.